# Is the famous singer Taylor Swift currently the most beautiful woman in the world?

Tags: human-biology

Is Ms. Taylor Swift currently the most beautiful woman in the world? Is she even in the top 10 or even the top 100? And if not, who is currently the most beautiful woman in the world? I apologize if this question may seem stupid, but I believe it is on-topic because sexual attractiveness in animal species, including humans, falls within the province of biology.

Comment: No. She is not. I never knew who she was, but I looked on Google Images. I live in Russia and see women more beautiful than she in the street every day.

Comment: The answers that could potentially be received by this question will most likely be completely subjective. **I would suggest that you instead explore how various cultures assess attractiveness**, since this does vary by culture, to ultimately find a culture that would find Taylor Swift's characteristics most appealing. From there, you would then identify all other women who also share strong expressions of these features, to then attempt a ranking that would establish a #1 most attractive woman. But even then, this ranking would be specific to the culture. So no, she's most likely not. VTC.

Comment: If you go on dirty sites, your hypothesis is easily disproven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the old saying about beauty being in the eye of the beholder?  Different cultures, and different individuals within cultures, have very different ideas of what constitutes beauty.  Consider the (IMHO overweight and flabby) "beauties" portrayed by Renaissance painters, for instance, or the apparently commonplace "butt enhancement" often reported in the news (when it goes wrong).

From a quick glance at Google Images, Ms. Swift is, to me, no more than moderately attractive.